# Modeling delayed feedback using logistic regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, predictive-models, exponential-distribution

Suppose we are trying to model the probability of a user clicking on an ad using logistic regression. We will receive only the positive feedback so, we define $Y = 1$ when success was observed, $Y=0$ otherwise.

We define the probability of click for a set of features $X$ as $$
P(y_i=1|X=x_i) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-wx_i}}
$$

Now suppose that you should predict the probability of click in real-time, one-by-one when the ad is displayed but the feedback will be delayed. And, in the same way, when you retrieve the data for training you will have actions with no feedback and therefore marked as $Y=0$ but you could receive positive feedback hours later and the label will change to $Y=1$.

Note that the data is non stationary because new features values (or instances) can appear within minutes, so training with data old enough to make sure that you received all the possible positive feedback is not an option.

Here is an example showing the cumulative amount of clicks received per hours. As you can see we have received almost 25% of clicks in the first hour and the 85% in the 10th.

[image: Feedback decay]

The image is showing the actual decay (in red) and the exponential decay we are using to model it (in yellow). Following:

$$
N(t) = N_0 · e^{-\lambda t}\\
\lambda=-ln(0.15)/C\\
$$

where $N_0$ is the initial point and $C$ is elapsed hours to 85% (that's why $\lambda$ is computed using 0.15)

In this paper [Modeling Delayed Feedback in Display Advertising](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9eed/333dcaade2c1dd32590eff6b0c0e670a5674.pdf) they introduced the delay into the model itself but I am trying to use the exponential decay to model the output variable of the logistic regression for simplicity (I though it'd be easier to change labels than rewrite the optimizer). So, instead of

$$
y = \left\{\begin{matrix}
1 & \text{success observed}\\
0 & \text{otherwise} 
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

I am trying to train the model using

$$
y = \left\{\begin{matrix}
1 & \text{success observed}\\ 
N_0 · e^{-\lambda t} & \text{otherwise}
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

and setting $N_0$ as the average successful rate.

The problem is that I haven't seen any place where this method was used and I don't know if I am doing something terribly wrong.

- Is this approach valid?
- Any suggestion or different approach to introduce the delayed feedback in a logistic regression model?
- Logistic regression is good fitting binomial distributions but here I am using *soft* labels ($y \in (0, 1)$ instead of $y \in \{0, 1\}$). Is this approach valid or logistic regression isn't gonna work well?

Comment: I think you have to step back and explain your problem more. What exactly is non stationary etc. If you are making predictions at multiple times how do you associate success with one particular time.?

Comment: You don't receive the failures, right ?

Comment: @seanv507 the data is non stationary because new features values (or instances) can appear. I made predictions in real-time, one-by-one and I will receive the feedback using IDs to match.

I will try to edit the question adding these points but fill free to edit it meanwhile!

Comment: @BenoitSanchez You are right. I just receive the positive feedback.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to do... I would suggest that you explain the actual problem you are trying to solve (business /medical or whatever) and then let statisticians help you convert it to statistical model. One thing this reminds me of is survival models.. So you might look that up if you are unable to explain the true problem

Comment: I think you should also say a word about the features (other than time). I called them $X$ in my answer. The existence of these features would explain logistic regression. Otherwise no logistic regression is needed, it's just estimating a single probability $p$ : $P(Y=1|T)=p(1-e^{-\lambda T})$. Time cannot be a feature of logistic regression, it works differently.

Comment: Also It would probably help to have a non mathematical description of the situation. Eg : "I am sending promotional e-mails, and I record a feedback when people click on a URL in the e-mail, I want to estimate the probability they will eventually click"

Comment: I deleted my answer because I realized the problem was more difficult than I thought. It is very interesting. However I think there are too many points for a single question : estimating a truncated exponential distribution with additional condition ($p$) is already uneasy (a latent variable model) and if you add the logistic thing ($X$) then it becomes a full research topic. I haven't read the article fully, but I looks rather "inevitable": on my own I get similar formulas as they do. I don't think there is an easier way.

Comment: @decay you still haven't explained what 'new features values (or instances) ' means. Do you just mean that you just want to train with all the data before it has had a chance to be 'labelled' with a click- because that doesn't really make sense.  Just train with a ? 3 hour lag (so 1 = clicked within the first 3 hours).  If you need to extrapolate to 'lifetime' clicks, use the *trained* model with your exponential.   *There is no point using the wrong label for your training data* - the whole idea is to predict the correct click through rate, you can't label your training data with  wrong CTR

Comment: discrete time survival models might be suitable for you. You just use logistic regression to predict the probability of a click in one time interval given't you haven't had a click in the previous intervals ( eg 15 minute intervals).  you can add time as one of the input variables, but you don't have to.

Answer (score -1):

your problem reminds me a lot the delayed feedback in conversion modeling published by Olivier Chapelle few years ago:
http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=2623330.2623634
also available here: http://olivier.chapelle.cc/pub.html

The only difference is that you work with clicks and not conversions but the idea is the same. There are also simple baselines in his paper that could work for you.
Hope it helps.

Comment: This article is already mentioned into the original question.